# How to write multiple javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, events, scroll

I am trying to call two function on scroll event only with javascript (no jquery) but only one works at a time.

```
    window.onscroll = function() {cartFunction()};
    function cartFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
            document.getElementById("shopping-cart").className = "sticky-cart";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("shopping-cart").className = "";
        }
    }
    window.onscroll = function() {cartFunction()};
    function cartFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
            document.getElementById("scroll-top").className = "show";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("scroll-top").className = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not combine them?

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... });` - do that as many times as you like - but ... your other problem is that you've clobbered the `cartFunction`

Comment: Well they have exactly the same name, so the second one defined will just overwrite the first one, if you want two different functions then use different names.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - that's right - but just changing the function names wont fix the whole issue

Comment: `window.onscroll = function() {cartFunction()};` is precisely equivalent to `window.onscroll = cartFunction` (with the exception that the former will not pass along `this` or the `event` parameter or return the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1. You are defining the `cartFunction` function twice, so the second definition overwrites the first
2. You are using `windows.onload=`, in javascript a variable/property can only hold one value, so you are effectively clobbering the first value and overwriting it with the second

Either one of these problems alone would cause only the second incarnation of the `cartFunction` to be called - so both issues need to be addressed

Firstly, assuming that you want to keep the two functions separate, and as globally scoped functions, the simplest change to your code is:

```
function cartFunction1() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("shopping-cart").className = "sticky-cart";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("shopping-cart").className = "";
    }
}

function cartFunction2() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("scroll-top").className = "show";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("scroll-top").className = "";
    }
}

window.onscroll = function() {cartFunction1(); cartFunction2()};
```

Alternatively, the last line can be replaced with

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {cartFunction1(); cartFunction2()});
```

or even

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', cartFunction1);
window.addEventListener('scroll', cartFunction2);
```

As you can see, you can add multiple 'scroll' event listeners and they'll ALL be called

*Insert usual caveats about Internet Explorer 8 or earlier*

If, however, those two functions can be combined AND don't need to be globally scoped

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function cartFunction1() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("shopping-cart").className = "sticky-cart";
        document.getElementById("scroll-top").className = "show";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("shopping-cart").className = "";
        document.getElementById("scroll-top").className = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Well done ... seeing as I inadvertantly kept saying 'load' instead of 'scroll' until I just fixed it :p

Comment: Ohh. I am not good in javascript and used to do it with jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addEventListener` by adding on scrolling

```
 function runOnScroll_1(){
     //do you stufff
 }
 function runOnScroll_2(){
     //do you stufff
 }
 window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll_1);
 window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll_2);
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .
```

and many others you can add and call on scroll